# Error de conexión Combobox (select) dinámicos Con Php, Mysql y Jquery (Ajax)

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

Lo que sucede es que no me muestra en la parte del *select* las listas, pero no encuentro el error de porque no me cargan, ya que me dice que es un error en la parte de conexión.

Para dar una mejor explicación, lo que se tiene que hacer es que cuando de clic en "supplier" me debería dar una listado de los existentes para, después, en "part number" darme los filtrados por el "supplier"  y que los siguientes campos se llenen de manera automática.

Lo que puedo decir es que el problema esta en conexión, ya que este código corriendo en una MAC con MAMP sí funciona, pero al correrlo en Windows con xampp o con MAMP pero para windows no funciona.

`new-activity.php`

```
`<section class="tabla01">
            <div>
              <label>Supplier</label>
            </div>

            <div class="caja_proveedor">
              <div class="cajap">
                <select class="select-proveedores" id="proveedor" name="proveedor" required="required">
                  <option></option>
                </select>

              </div>
            </div>

        </section>

<!-- Función que despliega la información de la parte seleccionada-->
            <script>
              function myFunction() {
                var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
                document.getElementById("datos").innerHTML =x;
              }
            </script>
            <p name="datos" id="datos"></p><!--Muestra en pantalla la información de la parte-->

            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index2.js"></script>

        </section>`
```

`conexion.php`

```
<?php 
function getConn(){
  $mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','thanks');
  if (mysqli_connect_error($mysqli))
    echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
  return $mysqli;
}
```

`cargar_listas.php`

```
    <?php 
include 'conexion.php';

function getListas(){
  $mysqli = getConn();
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `proveedores` ORDER BY `proveedornombre` ASC";
  $result = $mysqli->query($query);
  $listas = '<option value="0"></option>';
  while($row = $result->fetch_array('MYSQLI_ASSOC')){
    $listas .= "<option value='$row[id]'>$row[proveedornombre]</option>";
  }
  return $listas;
}

echo getListas();
```

`cargar_partes.php`

```
   <?php 
include 'conexion.php';

function getpartes(){
  $mysqli = getConn();
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `partes` WHERE `proveedor` = '$id'";
  $result = $mysqli->query($query);
  $videos = '<option value=""></option>';
  while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
```

`index2.js`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'php/cargar_listas.php'
  })
  .done(function(listas_rep){
    $('#proveedor').html(listas_rep)
  })
  .fail(function(){
    alert('Hubo un errror al cargar los proveedores')
  })

   $('#proveedor').on('change', function(){
    var id = $('#proveedor option:selected').text()
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url:'php/cargar_partes.php',
      data: {'id': id}
    })
    .done(function(listas_rep){
      $('#mySelect').html(listas_rep)
    })
    .fail(function(){
      alert('Hubo un errror al cargar las partes')
    })
  })
})
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
imagen de error

Comment: El código va _como texto, con formato_. Lee [ask] y [por qué una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/).

Comment: lo intente pero en la parte de visualización cuando agrego un titulo para poner otro apartado me lo pega todo mal y diferente.

Comment: En la esquina derecha del editor, verás un `?`. La sección _Código_ te indica cómo agregarlo; también desde ahí podés acceder a la ayuda avanzada.

Comment: ¿Por qué dices _"Lo que puedo decir es que el problema esta en conexión"_? ¿Ves el mensaje de error en pantalla, cuál es?

Comment: Puedes agregar el ouput del error??? incluso texto e imagen, saludos, ya me ha pasado ese tipo de errores.

Comment: ya agregue la imagen del error.

Comment: Hay dos problemas, uno que causa mysqli_connect_error para regresar en error.  El error que nos mostró es que su llamaada a mysqli_connect_error es incorrecto.  Debe ser mysqli_connect_error(), y no mysqli_connect_error($mysql)  Corríje este y encontrar lo que es el problema con la conneción

Comment: muchas gracias sí funciono <3